# JSON + VB.NET: Send array of array of string

Tags: json, vb.net

I am sending a JSON object from VB.NET to my server like this:

```
Dim dictData As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
dictData.Add("familystreet", "Beethovenstraat 13") 
dictData.Add("familycity", "Amsterdam")

Dim nFamilyMembers As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))

Dim nFamilyMember1 As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
nFamilyMember1.Add("familymembername", "Ludwig van")
nFamilyMember1.Add("familymemberage", "234")
nFamilyMembers.Add(nFamilyMember1)

Dim nFamilyMember2 As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
nFamilyMember2.Add("familymembername", "Vincent van")
nFamilyMember2.Add("familymemberage", "184")
nFamilyMembers.Add(nFamilyMember2)

dictData.Add("familymembers", nFamilyMembers)

Dim sURL As String = "https://example.com/admin/api-create-remote"

Dim webClient As New WebClient()
Dim resByte As Byte()
Dim resString As String
Dim reqString() As Byte

Try
    webClient.Headers("content-type") = "application/json"
    reqString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictData, Formatting.Indented))
    resByte = webClient.UploadData(sURL, "post", reqString)
    resString = Encoding.Default.GetString(resByte)
    Console.WriteLine(resString)
    webClient.Dispose()
    Return True
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I receive the data on the server side like this:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$response = array("status" => "0", "message" => "");
$data = json_decode($postdata);

$familystreet = $data->familystreet;
$familycity = $data->familycity;
```

The first properties work fine.

However, the following lines then result in a server error:

```
foreach ($data->familymembers as $familymember) 
{
    $onefamilymember =  $familymember;

    $aFamilyMembername = $onefamilymember->familymembername;
    $aFamilyMemberAge = $onefamilymember->familymemberage;
```

I am sure that my VB.NET code to post the family members is not correct.

Why?

I  have used an online tool to post test data to the server, and it worked fine. This is what I had tried and which worked fine:

```
{
    "familystreet":"Beethovenstraat 13",
    "familycity":"Amsterdam",
    "familymembers" : [
        {
            "familymembername" : "Ludwig van",
            "familymemberage" : "234",
        },
        {
            "familymembername" : "Vincent van",
            "familymemberage" : "184",
        },
```

Can anybody tell me what my mistake in VB.NET is?

Thank you!

Edit: My code was fine, the error was something else. However, perhaps my code is helpful to anybody and should therefore not be deleted?

Comment: You have, in `dictData.Add("familymembers", nFamilyMember)` a non-existing object `nFamilyMember`, which is clearly the `nFamilyMembers` Dictionary you built before. You also have a missing double quote in the address. This all makes one think that this is not exactly the *real* code you're using, so it's not clear what we're debugging. Anyway, the first thing to do, on the VB.Net side, is to change `Encoding.Default` to `Encoding.UTF8`: on the Server side that encoding doesn't make any sense. Then read the response of the Server, your `resByte` value. -- `Formatting.Indented` is useless here.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you. I have improved my code. I had stripped it down and renamed variables to make it more easy to read. I have included your tipps. I don't get to resByte. It throws an error, so I get to this line: onsole.WriteLine(ex.Message). The exception is "(500) internal server error."

Comment: What I can suggest here is to set the Header and Method using the .Net pre-built values; e.g., `webClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/json"` and `webClient.UploadData(sURL, HttpMethod.Post.ToString(), reqString)`. But, try first to just send the JSON as string, setting `webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8` and calling `dim serverResponse = webClient.UploadString(sURL, [Your JSON])`, letting the internal HttpWebRequest do the rest. -- It's important that you dispose of the WebClient object. -- I don't use PHP, so I can't tell you whether the Server side is OK.